# Problem when removing unicode characters via do shell script, Error <text> number 1

Tags: applescript

I have a text that I wanted to simplify, by removing the unicode characters. It works fine when I run in bash, but I get a strange error when I run it in AppleScript.

```
set mytext to "SomeApp™ on the App Store"
log (do shell script "echo '" & mytext & "' | /usr/bin/iconv -c -s -f utf-8 -t ascii")
```

The reply is:

```
tell current application
do shell script "echo 'SomeApp™ on the App Store' | /usr/bin/iconv -c -s -f utf-8 -t ascii"
    --> error "SomeApp on the AppStore" number 1
Result:
error "SomeApp on the AppStore" number 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that, while the `-c -s` options prevent `iconv` from printing errors due to untranslatable characters, it'll still exit with an error status (specifically, a status of 1); AppleScript is detecting this and reporting it (that's the "number 1" part of its message). Here's an example of the same effect in the shell:

```
$ echo "SomeApp™ on the App Store" | /usr/bin/iconv -c -s -f utf-8 -t ascii || echo "There was an error, status = $?"
SomeApp on the App Store
There was an error, status = 1
```

You can suppress this by adding `|| true` to the shell command, which will make the overall command succeed even if `iconv` "fails". Unfortunately, it'll also prevent AppleScript from detecting other -- real -- errors; I don't know a way to fix this.

I'd also recommend using `quoted form of` rather than manually adding quotes around the string (which will fail completely if the string contains ASCII apostrophes). Something like this:

```
set mytext to "SomeApp™ on the App Store"
log (do shell script "echo " & (quoted form of mytext) & " | /usr/bin/iconv -c -s -f utf-8 -t ascii || true")
```

Comment: Thank you for the quoted string tip, it's something I've been seeing, but my brain simply refuses to absorb. I'll use that from now on. I didn't realize that simply or'ing to true would still return the string, brilliant!